# Add view in a SwiftUI Form without a Section

Tags: ios, swiftui

I did not succeed to add a view in a `Form` without being embedded in a `Section`, so I tried to make the `Section` "invisible" setting for `Section` the same background the `Form` has, but there are separators which I also have to hide, I found this `UITableView.appearance().separatorColor = UIColor(named: "Background")` which sets for separators the same colour the `Form` background has, but the problem is that this applies on the whole `Form` and I do not want that :(

Any idea how I could add a view in a `Form` without a `Section` or how to "hide" the section without to influence the other `Sections` in the `Form` ?

```
struct ContentView: View {

    init() {
        UITableView.appearance().separatorColor = UIColor(named: "Background")
    }

    var body: some View {

        Form {
            Section {
                Text("text1")
                Text("text2")
                Text("text3")
            }

            Text("View without section")
                .font(.title)
                .listRowBackground(Color("Background"))
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I am not getting why you should not be able to add a View to a Form without a Section. Is the code you provided not working if you remove the Section ?

Comment: @MarcT. SwiftUI adds that `Section` (white background) automatically, so even if I remove it from code the `Section` will still be there

Comment: I can not follow it. Is it about the background color of the cells ? Or why you dont use a List or a VStack if your layout requirements differ from the one Form is providing.

Comment: @MarcT. This screen is supposed to have Pickers and DatePickers as well, so I need a `Form` because I need the nice behaviour Pickers have when they are in a `Form`. Unfortunately, I have to add labels, buttons and other views which should not be embedded in a `Section` as "View without section" `Text` view look in the image

Comment: Ok, looks like the code you provided is not showing this problem and in the description there is also nothing mentioned about it. Of course if your intention is to get the Form behaviour your View will behave like a form. You can change the background color of the cells if this is what you are looking for or you can simply implement the Form Picker behaviour manual at your own. It would not be too difficult to do this.

Answer (score 7):

A little late but might help some others:

1. Place your content in a VStack (if you have more than a single element)
2. Set the `.listRowInset` to `EdgeInsets()`
3. Set the frame max width and height OR use spacers

Using frame:

```
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
    Text("Title").font(.headline)
    Text("Subheadline").font(.subheadline)
}
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
.background(Color(UIColor.systemGroupedBackground))
```

Using spacers (this solution adds slightly more padding on the top and bottom):

```
HStack {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Spacer()
        Text("Title").font(.headline)
        Text("Subheadline").font(.subheadline)
        Spacer()
    }
    Spacer()
}
.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
.background(Color(UIColor.systemGroupedBackground))
```

[image]

Full code:

```
NavigationView {
    Form {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Testing a title").font(.headline)
            Text("Testing a subheadline").font(.subheadline)  
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
        .background(Color(UIColor.systemGroupedBackground))
                
        Section(header: Text("Title and Category").bold()) {
           TextField("Title", text: $title)
           TextField("Category", text: $title)        
        }
    }
    .navigationTitle("Test Form")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in init()

```
 UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none
```

Comment: It works, but it removes the separators for the whole `Form` and I still need them for the first `Section`

Comment: Then simply use a VStack in Section.

Comment: @UsamaAzam But then it has separators. I have the same problem.